# How to create chatbot with predefined inputs and responses are given in python?

Tags: python

I have inputs and responses.

```
userList:["Hi","What is my commission?","yes"]
```

```
cbList: ["Hi Magiee,How can I help you?","Would you like to know your commission?","Can you help me with NPN number?"]
```

I tried like below:

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel("path",sheet_name='Sheet2')
print(data)
userList=data["User"].tolist()
cbList=data["CB"].tolist()
while True:
    userInput=input("User:")
    if userInput in userList:
        print(cbList)
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
```

I am getting error:`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.
I also tried with creating a dictionary with key and values guided by @Jammy.But I have same key with different values.It over written the last value with first value.
Please,suggest me how can i create chatbot with predefined inputs and responses are given?

Comment: HI, can you share all the code you have written?

Comment: Edit your question, dont put it in the comments section

Comment: Updated my question with what i have used so far.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the file you are reading please? :)

Comment: I included sample values of the file above as userlist and cblist.

Comment: the chatbot you are trying to make is not that easy, and needs to contains alot of `if` statements cause you want specific output for sequance of inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you can do is to create a dict of list like:

```py
import random
responses = {'Hi!': ['Hello there', 'hi man']}
default_responses = ['I dont know', 'GoodBye']
while True:
    user_input = input('User:')
    if user_input == 'exit':
        break
    print(random.choice(responses.get(user_input, default_responses)))
```

Explenation:

`random.choice` choose a random value from a list

`responses.get` trys to get value of `user_input` from the dict, and if not found gets a default valuie of `default_responses`

## Update

```py
while True:
    user_input = input('User:')
    if user_input == "What is my commission?":
        user_input = input('Would you like to know your commission?')
        if user_input == 'yes':
             user_input = input('Can you help me with NPN number?')
```

and so on

Comment: I also used with creating a dictionary but i have same key with different values.That's why i tried with while loop but it is giving str not callable.

Comment: @Navya what line gives you that?

Comment: Sorry. Am i confusing you? Previously i created a dictionary with key and values.But i have same key with different values.Last value is over written by first value. Then I used above code(posted code). You are also saying that create a dictionary with values,is it?

Comment: I am totally new to this creating a chatbot.

Comment: @Navya my dict is string to list of values, for example `Hi!` here in my dict can result one of those values: `['Hello there', 'hi man']`

Comment: But for specific inputs i have to get exactly specific values. Will it return any of the values from list?

Comment: @Navya what you are asking here is very compilcated, its not an easy task to write chatbot like this, and you will need to add alot of `if` statements, for each input

Comment: Ok. How can i achieve that type of chatbot with if-else satements? Please,can you suggest me?

Comment: @Navya checkout my updated answer, and mark it as correct if that what you are searching for :)

Comment: With updated answer again I am getting ```str object not callable``` error.

Comment: @Navya i just ran it, did you run the exaclty same code? maybe you override the keyword `input`?

Comment: Iam getting error at line 2```user_input=input('User:')```

Comment: @Navya did you run it in python interpreter? in the cmd? try to restart it, you probably override the `input` function some lines before

Comment: It not giving response after gave the yes as input

Comment: @Navya well i didn't write you the chatbot, i just show you how to create it, you need to add the rest by your self, also mark the answer as correct if it what you was looking for :)

Comment: Ok. I just said that it is not giving response. I'll try by myself. Thank you @Reznik

Comment: @Navya no problem :) mark my answer as the correct one with the V sign :)

Comment: Hi @Reznik, I have one doubt,Can you help me?